# UITableViewCell's accessary arrow is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an app in xcode 6.1. i want to change tableview style to  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator i had don it programaticaly and using storyboard also but not showing an arrow. What is the reason below is my code. and also when i am changing my table view style through storyboard it is showing in storyboard but not on simulator.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [self.My dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Brand_Name"];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor brownColor];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Hoefler Text" size:17.0];
    // here just like follow ur other details
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
     cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"drugs.jpg"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you set all auto layout constraints?

Comment: just try  cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor]; or cell.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: The issue may be because of the cell you designed in the storyboard or with the properties you set in the table view or cell in the story board. There is no issue with your code written in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set accessory in yours storyboard cell options, "accessory":

[image]

Comment: same showing on storyboard but not showing on simulator

Comment: delete this row:   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and the issue was that the Tableview in the Storyboard was not pinned to the right side (as constraint).
So when running the app, the tableview turned out to be much wider then the screen, so the arrow was hidden. I fixed it by setting the constraints properly.